# Templated helper Functions to call specific templated children with specific function

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I am sure this can be done since it can probably done with a c macro, but can't wrap my head around the syntax. or if it's even possible.

Say I have class B and class C, both implementing function foo(int), both inheriting A, but when I call my helper I don't want to know the type(say I call with enum type, something like this:

I was thinking along the way of, but can't get the final touch:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;
struct A {};

template< typename R, typename C, typename... Args > R member_func(R (C::*)(Args...));

template<typename Child_t, typename Child_t::* func, typename ...Args_t>
auto activate(A& parent, Args_t... args) -> decltype(member_func(Child_t::func)) { return static_cast<Child_t&>(parent).*func(forward<Args_t>(args)...); }

template<typename (???)::* func, typename ...Args_t>
auto activate(int type, A& parent, Args_t... args) -> decltype(??? they would both return the same thing) { 
    switch (type) {
        case 0: return activate<B>(parent, forward<Args_t>(args)...);
        case 1: return activate<C>(parent, forward<Args_t>(args)...);
    }
}
struct B : public A { int test(int i) { return i; } };
struct C : public A { int test(int i) { return i+1; } };
void foo() {
    int type = 0;
    A* child = new B;
    cout << activate(type, *child, ??test??, 4) << endl;
}
```

Is it even possible?
Hints? taking suggestions for question name :)

Comment: Don't you need a dynamic cast instead when you write `return static_cast<Child_t&>(parent)`?

Comment: no, I know exactly what child type it is.

Comment: Yeah, this kind of leads me to the second question; are you trying to call a function defined in your class `C` even though you instantiated a class `B`?

Comment: noo... trying to call B.., type 0 is B

Comment: Then what you need is a big if-else with dynamic casts to select which child was actually instantiated and simply call `dynamic_cast<X&>(child).foo( ... )`.

Comment: It is possible to use a function object to select the member function: `struct test_wrapper { template<typename O, typename... Args> auto operator()(O&& o, Args&&... args) -> decltype(std::forward<O>(o).test(std::forward<Args>(args)...)) { return std::forward<O>(o).test(std::forward<Args>(args)...); } };` (In C++14, you'd usually use a polymorphic lambda for that.) Then you can pass `activate(type, *child, test_wrapper{}, 4)`

Comment: @dyp Wouldn't the `decltype(o)` part return the parent type though?

Comment: @Sh3ljohn I have removed the polymorphic lambda part since it's irrelevant here. In the manual function object implementation, I don't have any `decltype(o)`.

Comment: dyp can you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 2):

You can call member functions with the same name of unrelated classes via a function template:

```
template<typename O, typename... Args>
auto test(O&& o, Args&&... args)
-> decltype( std::forward<O>(o).test(std::forward<Args>(args)...) )
{
    return std::forward<O>(o).test(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

Function templates, like overload sets, cannot be passed directly to another function as an argument. A common solution to that problem is to wrap them in a function object type:

```
struct test_wrapper
{
    template<typename O, typename... Args>
    auto operator()(O&& o, Args&&... args)
    -> decltype( std::forward<O>(o).test(std::forward<Args>(args)...) )
    {
        return std::forward<O>(o).test(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
};
```

We'll aim at writing the call in the following way:

```
activate(type, *child, test_wrapper{}, 4)
```

The OP's `activate` function template still needs to figure out the return type. There are several options, all of which have drawbacks:

1. Use the return type of the first case.
2. Find a common type for all cases.
3. Supply a return type from outside.

Since the last one is probably the simplest, I'll use that for now. The call becomes `activate<int>(type, *child, test_wrapper{}, 4)`

```
template<typename Child_t, typename A, typename F, typename ...Args_t>
auto activate(A& parent, F f, Args_t... args)
-> decltype( f(static_cast<Child_t&>(parent), std::forward<Args_t>(args)...) )
{ return f(static_cast<Child_t&>(parent), std::forward<Args_t>(args)...); }

template<typename Ret, typename A, typename F, typename ...Args_t>
Ret activate(int type, A& parent, F f, Args_t... args) { 
    switch (type) {
        case 0: return activate<B>(parent, f, std::forward<Args_t>(args)...);
        case 1: return activate<C>(parent, f, std::forward<Args_t>(args)...);
    }
}
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/74018461723104f2)

Comment: note that you did not resolve activate's return type, so you must specifically  create a wrapper for each function?

Comment: I'd suggest refactoring the second `activate` into a generic switch and a function object that calls the first `activate`.

Comment: The return type of `activate` can be deduced in options 1 and 2. Yes, you need to create a function object wrapper for each different member function *name*. That's true even in C++14, where we can use polymorphic lambdas to reduce the boilerplate. This is one of the issues where a macro still could be useful.

Comment: Is this not a case where you could use `std::result_of` (cf my updated post)?

Comment: @Sh3ljohn For what purpose? Replacing the current `decltype` or implementing one of the options?

Comment: @dyp Replacing the `decltype` but I guess it is just as clear like this. Your solution looks nice!

Comment: @Sh3ljohn I'm not sure if you can use it for the function object type. For the first overload of `activate`, `typename std::result_of<F(Child_t&, Args...)>::type` would probably work - though I'd rather just replace it with `decltype(auto)` in C++14, since I don't care about SFINAE here.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible as presented, because the `activate` overload taking `int type` is only passed a single member function pointer, but needs to forward to the other `activate` overload with a different member function pointer for each supported type (i.e. either `&B::test` or `&C::test`).

Comment: oh boy so I must use macro and duplicate it as the amount of arguments??

Comment: I don't know what you actually want to achieve, because you did not describe that. So, I can't answer that.

Answer (score 0):

<del>Compiling your method `activate` (forgetting about the return type for a sec) will not work, because only one of your switch options calls the right activate overload, and all the others include a `return static_cast<X&>(parent)` which is invalid for any statement `A *child = new Y;` with `Y` not same as `X`.</del>

Here is how I understand what you are trying to do; you have a bunch of classes, say `B1` ... `Bn` that derive from a class `A`. All `Bi`s implement a method `T foo( ... )` where both the output and inputs are the same for all `i`, but `A` does not implement this method. You want a generic way to store `Bi` for any `i`, so you naturally write `A *child = new Bi`, but then you are wondering about how to call the appropriate method `foo`.

There are several ways to do this. Since the method foo always has the same prototype, the easiest way is probably to declare `foo` as virtual or pure virtual in `A`.

If you don't want to use virtual, then you could use something like

```
template <class T, class... Args>
typename std::result_of< decltype( &T::foo( Args... ) )(T) >::type
call_foo( T& X, Args... args )
    { return X.foo( std::forward<Args>(args)... ); }
```

which you could potentially use in your function `activate`.

Comment: I don't know why you're hung on dynamic_cast, it's perfectly fine, and I use templates specifically to avoid virtuals.

Comment: @dyp My bad, I thought using `static_cast` for "downwards" casts was incorrect.

Comment: `&T::foo(Args...)` is not valid as far as I can tell.